# SQL Server Group By X hours/days/weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering how you would be able to group records by X days (and the other supported `DATEPART` periods).

I have found two ways to group by one day/month/... using the following queries:

```
/** Group by one day method 1 **/
SELECT 
    SUM(Id) AS Id, 
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateTime)) AS DateTime 
FROM 
    Reporting
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateTime))
ORDER BY 
    DateTime DESC

/** Group by one day method 2 **/
SELECT 
    SUM(Id) AS Id, 
    MIN(DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateTime))) AS DateTime 
FROM 
    Reporting
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(YEAR, DateTime), 
    DATEPART(MONTH, DateTime), 
    DATEPART(DAY, DateTime)
ORDER BY 
    DateTime DESC
```

I was hoping that it would be as easy as to increase the number 0 in the queries but that does not seem to work. Is there an easy solution for this because I could not find any examples on the web?

One other requirement would be that the start of the period (and -if easy- the end) should be added as column(s) (type: dateTime).

Can anybody push me in the right direction with this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The question is probably not very good explained, the answer that is given does help me further. I will post another question with my specific use case if I get stuck again.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What does "group by x days" mean?

Comment: Your question is not clear.   If you want to group by 2 days, and there are records on three consecutive days, which two should get grouped together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group by periods of days (or other date parts), you can use arithemtic:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, 10 * (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateTime) / 10) ) as DateTime,
       SUM(Id) as Id
FROM Reporting
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateTime))
ORDER BY MIN(DateTime) DESC;
```

SQL Server does integer division, so this truncates the dates to the multiple of 10 (or whatever) less than the value.  You could be a bit clearer by using `floor`()`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, 10 * FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateTime) / 10) ) as DateTime,
       SUM(Id) as Id
FROM Reporting
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateTime))
ORDER BY MIN(DateTime) DESC;
```

Comment: tnx @gordon-linoff

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aggregate Window Functions](https://drill.apache.org/docs/aggregate-window-functions/) to isolate the grouping logic in your select statement. Here's a full example:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), dt DATETIME)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT GETDATE() dt
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, dt)
    FROM cte 
    WHERE dt > GETDATE() - 10
)
INSERT INTO @table (dt) 
SELECT * FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);  

SELECT 
CAST(dt AS DATE) AS DayPart, 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(dt AS DATE), 0) AS DayCount,
DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, dt), 0) AS HourPart, 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, dt), 0)) AS HourCount,
dt
FROM @table
```

Returns:

```
DayPart     DayCount    HourPart                    HourCount   dt
2018-07-06  82          2018-07-06 10:00:00.000     4           2018-07-06 10:57:16.887
2018-07-06  82          2018-07-06 10:00:00.000     4           2018-07-06 10:47:16.887
2018-07-06  82          2018-07-06 10:00:00.000     4           2018-07-06 10:37:16.887
2018-07-06  82          2018-07-06 10:00:00.000     4           2018-07-06 10:27:16.887
2018-07-06  82          2018-07-06 11:00:00.000     6           2018-07-06 11:57:16.887
2018-07-06  82          2018-07-06 11:00:00.000     6           2018-07-06 11:47:16.887
2018-07-06  82          2018-07-06 11:00:00.000     6           2018-07-06 11:37:16.887
2018-07-06  82          2018-07-06 11:00:00.000     6           2018-07-06 11:27:16.887
... etc
```