# Select the highest value of every N days

Tags: t-sql

```
| Date | Price |
| 2022-05-11 04:00:00.0000000 +00:00  | 1    |
| 2022-05-12 04:00:00.0000000 +00:00  | 2    | 
| 2022-05-13 04:00:00.0000000 +00:00  | 3    |
```

I have a long table which looks like above with various timestamps. I would like to select the highest price of every N days. How should I do the grouping?

Comment: Does one of the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364893/sql-server-group-by-x-hours-days-weeks help you?

Comment: Thank You, I believe this will be the one!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @EdmCoff, In my case the answer looks like

````
select MAX(Price)
from MyTable
Group by DATEADD(DAY, 0, 3 * FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Date) / 3) )
order by min(Date) asc```
````